# Content scrolling with DockPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, wpf-controls

I'm facing problem with scrolling content in Dock panel .
My controls placed in 'DockPanel' as below

```
<DockPanel>
<ScrollViewer>
 <StackPanel>
   <!-- Here controls are like Radiobutton,Lable ,CheckBox,Textblock are added dynamically in grid.-->
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I'm using only vertical scrollbar, not need horizontal scrollbar,
When I first time traverse through controls in 'DockPanel' by using tab ,Tab focus goes off the screen but panel is not scrolling down.

Please help me out  I'm really stuck over here.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: plus 1 for the beneficial question , i was looking for something similar a long time ago

Answer (score 3):

Add `IsTabStop="True"` in `Scrollviewer`:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ScrollViewer IsTabStop="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <StackPanel></StackPanel>                
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: awesome thank you , i didn't even know we can specify a scrollbar in DockPanel's lol